# how to end tmux sequence after switching panes

Tags: tmux

In tmux, when having separate panes open, I do `Ctrl-B ↑` to switch to the pane above. Great. Except that if the next key I want to press is also an arrow key (e.g. I want to go to the bash prompt above and search history for previous command) then this keystroke is **also** interpreted by tmux.

It seems there's a timeout period before tmux releases control of the keyboard. How can I reduce that?

Comment: There are more solutions to a similar question over here -> https://superuser.com/questions/325110/how-to-turn-down-the-timeout-between-prefix-key-and-command-key-in-tmux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure this with the `repeat-time` option:

> **repeat-time** time
>                      Allow multiple commands to be entered without pressing the prefix-key again in the specified time
>                      milliseconds (the default is 500).  **Whether a key repeats may be set when it is bound using the -r
>                      flag to bind-key**.  Repeat is enabled for the default keys bound to the resize-pane command.